# When an app runs, the other one is removed

Tags: android, eclipse

I have two app's projects in two different Eclipse's workspaces. When I run one of the apps, the other is removed from my phone and I can't figure out why. I have already tried cleaning up each project (Eclipse->Project->Clean...) because I suspected that it was some kind of Eclipse's mess, but it didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you named them differently in your manifest? If they share the same properties, then the installer could mistake one for the other, and remove the "old" one when installing the new one.

Comment: Just to make this clear: The package name is the relevant identifier here. It is *(or at least should be)* unique for every app. If your apps share the same package name, they will get recognized as different versions of the same app by the system. Which triggers an update that uninstalls the previous version before installing the new apk.

Comment: Thanks Guys. I was so worried with the apps names that I forgot to change the packages names.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, although it should be @alextsc ;)

Comment: Nah, teamwork for the win. :) Take the points, I got enough of them. :P